# Should US citizens get a visa in advance for a one-week trip to Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, hong-kong

I'm US Citizen and I'm planing a one week trip to Hong Kong for pleasure. Do I need to get a visa in advance?

This [site](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1136.html) seems to indicate that I do not need to as long as I have a passport that is valid for at least 6 months.

> **ENTRY/EXIT REQUIREMENTS: FOR U.S. CITIZENS:** To enter Hong Kong, you will need a passport that is valid for at least one month beyond the date of your intended stay, adequate funds to cover your stay without working locally, and evidence of onward/return transportation. Many neighboring areas require that your passport is valid for at least six months before they will allow you to enter, so if you plan on regional travel beyond Hong Kong, make sure that your passport is valid for at least six months beyond the date you plan to enter such areas. You do not need a visa for tourist visits of up to 90 days. You may be granted an extension of your stay if you apply to the Hong Kong SAR Immigration Department. You must have an appropriate visa to work or study in Hong Kong. Visit the Hong Kong SAR Immigration Department or the Embassy of the People's Republic of China website for the most current visa information.

However, if anyone knows otherwise i would appreciate a heads up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hong Kong SAR has fairly relaxed rules for visa-free entry ranging from 14 to 90 days to a large range of nationalities. The official rules to list you are supposed to prove you have sufficient funds to cover your travel and evidence of onwards travel. However, in practice I have rarely found HK Border Control officials asking anyone to show this evidence or denying visas. They usually just ask you verbally when you plan to leave the country and take your word for the answer.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't have these of course. Perhaps they'll only ask if you look shifty; if you wear an eye-patch and have a parrot on your shoulder. (Note - the parrot probably won't be allowed in.)

Honestly, the Hong Kong / State Dept website advice is very clear and straightforward; this just feels more like a case of travel nerves. Don't worry, for the duration you're going for it shouldn't raise any flags - and enjoy your trip! :)

Answer (score 6):

The information you have is consistent with that given by the [Hong Kong immigration authorities](http://www.immd.gov.hk/ehtml/hkvisas_4.htm) in that US passport holders may visit Hong Kong for leisure purposes for up to 90 days without a visa.

(Note that the US State Department website which you quote says that you only need a passport valid for at least one month after the planned travel dates. The six months rule is only a caution because many countries require a passport valid for 6 months.)

I suspect that the State Department probably has the 1 month limit right, but if you really want to play it safe and your passport is about to expire, renew it (a good idea in any case). Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that info on the HK Immigration Department website.

Answer (score 2):

US citizens do not need visa to enter Hong Kong. This website is very helpful for all visa and passport requirement to enter a country when you travel.

http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/HK-Hong-Kong-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Enjoy your trip. Hong Kong is a very fun place to visit. :)