# What would be considered "evidence of adequate funds" for entering Hong Kong?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, money, regulations, hong-kong, proof-of-funds

I'll be visiting Hong Kong for a few days next week.  I noticed this statement on the [Hong Kong Visa Requirements](http://hongkong.usconsulate.gov/acs_hkvisa.html) page:

> must have a U.S. passport valid for at least six months and evidence of adequate funds for their stay and onward transportation.

What would qualify as "evidence of adequate funds"?

Comment: In terms of the "onward transportation" either a flight ticket or other transport method ticket (or Cruise Ship ticket for example) is good. If you have a visa for a country that is reachable cheaply (China, Macao), you should be fine without that.

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/should-i-get-a-visa-in-advance-for-a-one-week-trip-to-hong-kong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Evidence of adequate funds is usually:

- A bank account statement for the last few months (usually 3 months) showing a good amount of money to cover your stay.
- Another evidence in case of business trips would be a letter from your employer stating that the employer is covering the trip expenses.
- A job certificate showing your income can also work, I have submit it before and it was accepted to obtain visas for different countries.
- If you have an invitation letter to attend an event and it shows that expenses will be covered, this will also work.

Anyway, in your case since you will obtain your visa upon arrival most likely you will not be asked. Keep a copy of your bank account statement just in case the immigration officer asked you to show the evidence. I also guess showing credit cards or cash will work too.

Answer (score 6):

I've only ever had to show this when reentering Mexico from a sidetrip to Central America, or when extending my tourist visa in Mexico.

It's been a few years (six to eight) but at that time they always accepted a printout of my bank balance from my bank's online banking website, and even just having a credit card. There was no attempt to verify the printout wasn't photoshopped or that the credit card wasn't maxed out.

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained what “evidence of adequate funds” is in general but for Hong Kong specifically, none of this seem to really matter in practice. Traveling on a European passport, got in by plane, went to Macao and back  by ferry, my passport and those of other people traveling with me were stamped quickly every time without asking much or looking at any documentation (not even the return ticket as far as I remember, I think I got a little form to return when leaving).

All this is obviously anecdotal but they did check passports' validity and a Turkish acquaintance faced real problems in Macao because his passport would expire before the end of the 90 days allowed.

I do not know if US passport holders are treated differently but the rules are apparently the same (90 days of visa free stay).

Comment: +1.  In general, evidence of adequate funds is a bit of a "cover your ass" excuse for Immigration: if they suspect you're coming in trying to work illegally, it's easier to deport you for not having proof of funds now.